# Apply CSRF token constraint selectively on routes for a sailsjs or expressjs app

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

Is it possible to apply CSRF token check selectively on certain requests/routes? If I want to apply for 4 out of 6 post requests used in my application, will it be possible? Has CSRF token any relevance for GET request? As reference document for sailsjs says "When CSRF protection is enabled, all **non-GET** requests to the Sails server must be accompanied by a special token, identified by either a header or a parameter in the query string or HTTP body." Is it same for normal expressjs based app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only option I found regarding "selectively" enabling / disabling CSRF tokens was at [this documentation](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-csrf), which allows a kind of "blacklist" csrf will be disabled for. So your csrf.js in the config folder would look like this:

```
module.exports.csrf = {
  // it says comma delimited list in the docs, but not sure if it has to look exactly like this,
  // the docs seem to be a bit unclear
  routesDisabled: "POST /model,DELETE /model/:id" 
};
```

---

CSRF has usually no relevance for GET requests, as these should be without any side effects (if REST conform). CSRF tokens are an authenticity token to proof to the web server / backend on a modifying request (i.e. post, put delete) that you (the visitor / user) were not fooled by someone else with an evil intention (e.g. like a faked form for a simple renaming action, which in turn tries to delete your account behind the scenes).

So the csrf token proofs that the form was generated by the server / backend you want to make the request to.

I'm not so sure about the csrf token regarding express.js apps.
But since sails.js is based on express.js, it could be the same mechanism.

Comment: Is there a way to do this in an array or something? Its not very intuitive when you have a long list (for example, a mobile app may have post requests without CSRF because we come up with our own mechanism for this)

Comment: @KVISH Yes, the [docs](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-csrf) state that this options also accepts an array: `Array or comma-delimited list of routes where CSRF protection is disabled. Routes with Express-style wildcards (e.g. '/foo/:id') and regular expressions (e.g. /user\/\d+/) can both be used.`